Как побороть ошибку Failed to get emoji data?
Не могу побороть эту ошибку Failed to get emoji data. Конфликта с другими плагинами быть не может так как активирован кроме этого только buddypress. Выбор и вставка эмодзи происходит корректно? А ошибка все вылезает.
// Emoji button click event
    jQuery('#bpemoji-button').click(function() {
        console.log('Emoji button clicked');
        jQuery('#emoji-picker-container').toggle();
    });

    // Add emoji picker
    var emojiPicker = jQuery('<div class="emoji-picker"></div>');
    var emojis = ['','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','☺️','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','‍️','','','','','‍','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','‍','','','','','','','','','','','☹️','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','☠️','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','️','✋','','','','','✌️','','','','','','','','','','','','✊','','','','','','','','','','❤️','❤️‍','','','⚠️',''];
    emojis.forEach(function(emoji) {
        emojiPicker.append('<span class="emoji" data-emoji="' + emoji + '">' + emoji + '</span>');
    });
    jQuery('#emoji-picker').append(emojiPicker);

    // Emoji click event
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.emoji', function() {
        var emoji = jQuery(this).data('emoji');
        console.log('Emoji selected: ', emoji);
        if (typeof emoji !== 'undefined' && emoji !== null && emoji !== '') {
            var textarea = jQuery('#whats-new');
            textarea.val(textarea.val() + ' ' + emoji);
            jQuery('#emoji-picker-container').hide();
            textarea.trigger('change');
        } else {
            console.error('Failed to get emoji data');
        }
    });
});


Дебажить и смотреть, что у вас в emoji и почему ваш IF сваливается в else(Выведете все значения из if в консоль

Все что отображает консоль! Emoji button clicked
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:71 Emoji selected:  undefined
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:78 Failed to get emoji data
(анонимная) @ bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:78
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:71 Emoji selected:

Выведете отдельно в консоль jQuery(this). Судя по всему, у вас идет погружение событие клика и первый элемент как раз без data-emoji, а вот следующий уже получает данные(событие то у вас висит на всем DOM).

Вот что отображает консоль.  Document ready
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:69 e. [button#bpemoji-button]0: button#bpemoji-buttonlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Object(0)
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:56 Emoji button clicked
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:57 e. [button#bpemoji-button]0: button#bpemoji-buttonlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Object(0)
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:74 Emoji selected:  undefined
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:81 Failed to get emoji data
(анонимная) @ bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:81
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
bpgiphy.js?ver=1.5:74 Emoji selected:
